# Selecting entries of a pytorch tensor with another tensor

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor `a` with with float entries and `torch.Size([64,2])` and I also have a tensor `b` with `torch.Size([64])`. The entries of `b` are only `0` or `1`.

I would like to get a new tensor `c` with `torch.Size([64])` such that `c[i] == a[i,b[i]]` for every index i. How can I do that?

**My attempt**
I tried with `torch.gather` but without success. The following code gives me `RuntimeError: Index tensor must have the same number of dimensions as input tensor`

```
import torch
a = torch.zeros([64,2])
b = torch.ones(64).long()
torch.gather(input=a, dim=1,index=b)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform this straight with an indexing of `a` on both dimensions:

- On `dimension=0`: a "sequential" indexing using [`torch.arange`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.arange.html).
- On `dimension=1`: indexing using `b`.

All in all, this gives:

```
>>> a[torch.arange(len(a)), b]
```

---

Alternatively you can use [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html), the operation you are looking for is:

```
# c[i] == a[i,b[i]]
```

The provided gather operation when applied on `dim=1` provides something like:

```
# c[i,j] == a[i,b[i,j]]
```

As you can see, we need to account for the difference in shapes between between `a` and `b`. To do so, you can unsqueeze a singleton dimension on `b` (annotated with the letter `j` above) such than `#b=(64, 1)`, for instance with `b.unsqueeze(-1)` or `b[...,None]`:

```
>>> a.gather(dim=1, index=b[...,None]).flatten()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Now I understand what I was missing in oder to use gather..  :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, but I think ou can loop over your tensor

```
a = torch.zeros([64,2])
b = torch.ones(64).long()
c = torch.empty([64])
for i, _ in enumerate(a):
  c[i] = a[i,b[i]]
c
```